# jQuery Script called from within php While loop not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, while-loop

I have a php partial page that grabs images from a MySQL database and prints them in the browser using a `while` loop. A jQuery function is called when I click on one of the images - this function is supposed to grab the `src` of the `img` and then alert the user what that `src` is in a pop-up window. This `src` should change depending on which `img` is clicked.

The resulting page is a series of images and their respective data fields, as seen in this snapshot:

[image]

Unfortunately, the same `src` is alerted, regardless of which `img` is clicked, and it appears to be the last `img` that was printed from the while loop.

This is the alert that pops up on `img` click - it should be unique for every photo, but it's the same source currently:

[image]

How can I get this `img` `src` that is alerted to be unique for every `img` that is clicked?

**EDIT:** I should also say that, when tested outside of the while loop, this jQuery script seems to work as expected - different images that are clicked alert different `src` attributes.

```
 <div id="screenings">
    <?php

        //MySQL database connection established

        ...

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<div class='img_div'>";
                echo "<img class='modal_img img_screenings' ng-click=\"vm.openModal('custom-modal-1')\" src='images/".$row['image']."' >";

                ...

            echo "</div>";
        }
    ?>
 </div>

 <modal id="custom-modal-1">
     <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-body">
                <img id="popup_img" src="#">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-background"></div>
</modal>

<script>
    $('.img_div').on("click", function() {
        var source = ( $('.modal_img').attr("src") );
        alert(source);
        $('#popup_img').prop('src', this.src);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The PHP and `while` are irrelevant here, can you add the generated source to the question. I think you should use `$(this)` in place of `$('.modal_img')` but I'd need to test that, I rarely work with JS

Comment: Do you mean what this partial will look like in the full html context?

Comment: What does the `echo "<div class='img_div'>";` and other PHP generate?

Comment: Ah, I see - updated with a snapshot for context. I'm trying to build a modal pop-up window that works with these images.

Comment: Added a picture of the alert pop-up as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `var source = ( $('.modal_img').attr("src") );` That will get the first src attribute of an item matching the class. But all the images have the same class. You should use `$(this)` inside `$('.img_div').on("click", function() {` to reference the clicked `<div>`. Try `var source = $(this).find('img').attr('src'));` which should get the `<img>` tag src attribute of the first img inside the clicked `$(this)` item.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thank you!